# Is it possible access a pointer in a "recursive mode"?

Tags: c, string, pointers

Is there in C language a way to do something like:

```
/* it's a demo code. I know that it doesn't work. */
char foo[] = "abc";
char* p = &foo[0];
int len = 3;

while(len) {
    printf("%c", *p);
    p--;
    len--;
}
```

and get `cba` output?

My question is: there any simple way to do this? maybe using arithmetic pointers. I know that I can write an function-like:

```
/* Note: I haven't tested the this code. But I believe that works. */
char *strrev(char input[]) {
    if (input == NULL) return NULL;

    int len = strlen(input) - 1;
    char * rev = malloc(len+1);

    if (rev == NULL) return NULL;

    for (; len != 0; len--) *rev++ = input[len];

    if (len == 0) {
      *rev++= '\0';
       return rev;
    } else {
       free(rev);     
       return NULL;
    }   
}
```

But I'm looking for more simple way, I need write a function that starts the comparisons from half string.

Comment: Not sure if i understand you correctly, but the modulus operator (`%`) might just be what you're looking for. If you do e.g. `(5+1)%5`, this will evaluate to `1` (it kind of wraps around the numbers).

Comment: Side note: In your first example, you may want to go from `&foo[2]` back. Otherwise you are going below the memory that is yours. Also, you meant to get `cba` right?

Comment: Is this homeork?  If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: If you mean "reverse" instead of "recursive", and "cba" instead of "bca", then the mistake in the code is, that you set the pointer `p` at the beginning of your array. You should set it to the end of it, like `char* p = &foo[2];`, or better yet, `char* p = &foo[strlen(foo)-1];
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void backwards_print(const char *text) {
    /* don't even try to print an empty string */
    if (*text) {
        const char *p = text;

        /* go to the end */
        while (*p++) /* void */;

        /* print from the end */
        while (p != text) putchar(*--p);

    }
    putchar('\n'); /* newline, flush buffer */
}
```

Example usage

```
char foo[] = "abc";
backwards_print(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start p at foo[2] and loop while(p >= &foo[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start, at the start of the `while` loop `p` is pointing to the first character i.e. a. Then you are going to the character before - which does not exist!

Also - Jack - Why put code up that you have not tried?

Answer (score 0):

If a rotation is what you want,

```
int index = 1;
static const int kArraySize = sizeof(foo) / sizeof(char);

while(len) {
    printf("%c", p[index++ % kArraySize]);
    len--;
}
```

This will print `bca`.  If you want a reversal, then it will be different.

FYI, I'd code these loops a bit different if it were my code, but I wanted to re-use your code as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to work your way to the middle from both ends, like this?

```
len = strlen(input) - 1;
for (i = 0; i <= len/2; ++i) {
  char c = input[i];
  input[i] = input[len - i];
  input[len - i] = c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, you need a function like this:

```
// returns a pointer to the start of 'dst'
// assumes dst has a length = strlen(str) + 1 or more
// also assumes that dst and src are not NULL.
char *strmidrev(char *dst, const char *src)
{
    int length = strlen(src);
    int mid = length / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        dst[i] = src[((i + mid) % length)];
    }

    // NUL terminate the string
    dst[length] = '\0';

    return dst;
}
```